# Flask Wtforms FileField object has no attribute read

Tags: python, amazon-s3, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to upload images to an Amazon S3 bucket from a Flask app. Here is my code:

```
def s3upload(image, acl='public-read'):
    key = app.config['S3_KEY']
    secret = app.config['S3_SECRET']
    bucket = app.config['S3_BUCKET']

    conn = S3Connection(key, secret)
    mybucket = conn.get_bucket(bucket)

    r = redis.StrictRedis(connection_pool = pool)
    iid = r.incr('image')
    now = time.time()
    r.zadd('image:created_on', now, iid)


    k = Key(mybucket)
    k.key = iid
    k.set_contents_from_string(image.read())

    return iid

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = ImageForm(request.form)
    print 'CHECKING REQUEST'
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.image:
        print 'VALID REQUEST'
        image = form.image.read()
        upload = s3upload(image)
        print upload
    else:
        image = None

    r = redis.StrictRedis(connection_pool = pool)
    last_ten = r.zrange('image:created_on', 0, 9)
    print last_ten
    images = []

    key = app.config['S3_KEY']
    secret = app.config['S3_SECRET']
    bucket = app.config['S3_BUCKET']

    conn = S3Connection(key, secret)
    mybucket = conn.get_bucket(bucket)  


    for image in last_ten:

        images.append(mybucket.get_key(image, validate = False))


    return render_template('index.html', form=form, images=images, image=image)
```

However I get an error at `k.set_contents_from_string(image.read())` saying `'FileField' object has no attribute 'read'`. Everything I've ready has indicated this is the proper way to upload an image to S3 and I've found several examples where they call `.read()` on a `FileField` object and it works fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You use `form.image.data.read()`. Ideally, you should stream the file contents instead of reading them into memory.

Comment: Can you post an example of how that would work please?

Comment: Had the same problem. Noticed a typo in `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute of the form.

Answer (score 1):

`FileField` objects have a `data` attribute:

```
k.set_contents_from_string(image.data.read())
```

Comment: Returns the same error `'FileField' object has no attribute 'stream'`

Comment: @haye321: Are you importing `FileField` from `flask_wtf` or from `wtforms`? You're probably importing it from `wtforms`, which may be the cause of your original problem as well.

Comment: I am importing it from `flask_wtf`.

Comment: @haye321: What version of Flask-WTF are you using?

Comment: I am using v.9.4, it was downloaded from pypi this morning.

Comment: @haye321: Whoops, I completely forgot the `.data` part. It should work now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49516/discussion-between-haye321-and-blender)

Comment: @haye321: You're still calling `image = form.image.read()`. You need just `upload = s3upload(form.image)`.

Comment: I've removed .read() and I was using exclusively .stream. When I removed both and just send `s3upload(form.image)` with `set_content_from_stream` it returns `BotoClientError: s3 does not support chunked transfer`

Comment: @haye321: That's odd. I guess you'll have to do what you originally were doing: `k.set_contents_from_string(image.data.read())`

Comment: That comes back to the initial problem. Using that returns `'unicode' object has no attribute 'read'`

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
import os

filestream = form.image.raw_data[0]
filestream.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
read_data = filestream.tell()
```

or

```
read_data = form.image.raw_data[0].read()
```